# Lose window manager boot but window data is still on disk

Tags: window

yesterday I tried to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu but then when I restart my laptop, I didn't start  Windows but it ran Ubuntu immediately.

Then I knew I just accidentally removed Windows boot manager. When I used `sudo fdisk` to check the disk I still saw my I basic data. Also, I saw a local disk which has my old Windows data on the 'other locations'. Please help me to recover Windows (you can remove Ubuntu if necessary).

I know many people have asked the same questions like me but from yesterday until now I cannot fix this. Ask if you want to see further configuration or disk on my Ubuntu.

Edit: One friend told me to use sudo os-prober to indentigy windows 10 install and then use sudo update-grub to update the GRUB. After typing os-prober, it said

> /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

but then when using update-grub. it cannot find windows but rather

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic

Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.

Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I also check check `/etc/default/grub` but there is no `GRUB_DIASBABLE_OS_PROBER`.

Comment: Have you changed anything in the BIOS in order to install Linux?

Comment: @harrymc I changed SATA

Comment: Before doing *anything* else, make a full disk image (which *should* have been done before adding Ubuntu). That would allow you to make changes to fix the issue, and to recover data if something goes wrong.